# Two Raid-1 arrays in a single system?

Tags: windows-7, raid

I'm building a Raid array for the first time in my system and I have a question regarding having multiple Raid-1 arrays in a single Win 7 system.

I'm a bit of an organizational freak with my data and I currently have two separate hard drives I want to mirror. The new motherboard I'm looking to buy supports Raid, so my questions are:

1. Can I have more than one Raid-1 array in a single system?
2. Would I have to buy a separate controller for the second array?

Comment: what make/model of the motherboard?  do you know what RAID chipset it uses?  most motherboards provide fakeRAID chips (the RAID is done mostly in the driver, not on the chip).

Answer (score 3):

If you have 4 sata slots and a raid chip on the motherboard, chances are that you can have 2 mirrored arrays.

Instead of having 4 drives just buy 2 larger ones and partition them once they are mirrored. That way you will save space in the case and a little bit of energy :)