# Having two different RAID configurations in a NAS

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

I am in the process of buying a new NAS and I am putting down some requirements in order to decide which brand / model suits me better.

Generally I can say that I am using two 'types' of files everyday

1. Some Very important files for which I need some replication / redundancy. Those are a lot small, document (in the majority) and image files.
2. Some large files in size, which I do not care if I lose and they are easily replaceable. These files are raw data, export or rip, which I use temporally but I want to 'share' them, and that why I want them on NAS.

I am thinking of buying a 4bay NAS and

- Configure the 3 slots (2TB or 3TB disks) in raid 5, to store the first 'type' or my files.
- Use the 4th slot as a single drive (6TB possible), to store the less important second 'type' of files.

Can a NAS configured this way? Are there any special hardware / Software requirements that a NAS should have?

Currently I am looking into QNAP's TS453 mini, TS451+ and TS453 Pro. I went through all the information I could find for them, but I did not find anything to state clearly if the aforementioned requirement is supported or not.

Note 1: Related to [Two Raid-1 arrays in a single system?](https://superuser.com/questions/126495/two-raid-1-arrays-in-a-single-system)
Note 2: While I am only mentioning some QNAP models, I am not bounded to them and this does not mean I will not 'try' another brand. They are just some model that fit my requirement and price range.
Note 3: This question is not to argue, which Raid configuration is better and why I am not putting everything in Raid 5/ 6 etc.

Comment: Depends on the make and model what you can do with the hardware. It will all be stated in the specifications or owners manual for each make and model.

Comment: @Moab, I update my question and I am mentioning some model that look into. I read any information I found about them, but it is not clear is they will support what I am trying to do.

Comment: Only the manufacturer would know, or someone who owns that particular model and has configured it that way with success, and that would be unlikely. Contact the support dept for that make/model, only they can give a definitive answer.